# Type theory with an Any/Variant type

Tags: types, grammar, language-design, variant, type-theory

Let's say I have a type system that has has three primitive types in addition to the `null` value:

- *null*
- `bool`
- `num`
- `string`

Additionally, there is a typed array for each of the types, so we now have: *null*, `bool`, `bool[]`, `num`, `num[]`, `string`, and `string[]` as all of our types.

Finally, we have an `Any` type that can contain any other type. For example, we might have two columns like this:

| id (num) | value (any) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "abc" |
| 2 | [1,2,3] |
| 3 | **[1, true]** ?? |

My question then is whether the `any[]` value, such as `[1, true]` is also contained within the `any` type (since it can be "anything"), or is `[1, true]` not a valid value for that type? In other words, what "types" do I need in my type-system -- option 1 or option 2 below?

1. *null*, `bool`, `bool[]`, `num`, `num[]`, `string`, `string[]`, and `any`
2. *null*, `bool`, `bool[]`, `num`, `num[]`, `string`, `string[]`, `any`, and `any[]`

And, if we only need the first version, does that then support recursion, such as `[[1, true], [2, "hi"]]` (that's two levels, i.e., `any[][]` and so so on), what about a jagged array, such as `[[1,"a"], 0]` ?

Comment: This is not clear. And what is your 1 question? What does 'an Any type that can contain any other type' mean exactly? What do you mean, 'it can be "anything"'? And what does putting 'anything' & 'types' in quotes mean? After you tell us what you mean, how do you not know "whether the any[] value ... is also contained within the any type"?

Answer (score 3):

A type system with (perhaps unnatural) limitations is still a type system.

Any of the possibilities you have laid out would be possible to define grammars for, fully specify, and implement. You could even do other things like allow recursion only to a fixed depth, or have separate jagged and non-jagged nested array types.

The answer to the question of whether a type system could work any of these ways, is yes in each case.

If you are deciding on the type system yourself, the question then becomes whether you *should* allow `any[]` and whether `any` should allow nested arrays or not. The answer to that question depends on what your reasons for working with a type system are. There’s no one best answer for all contexts here.

Comment: thanks for this. Have you seen any typed languages that support jagged arrays? Or is that sort of a fantasy that would need to be worked around with pointers and all. Maybe the closest I have seen is with M, though that's not a strictly typed language: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/power-query-m-type-system.

Comment: The closest thing to that I have seen to that is typed languages that support dynamically sized arrays and allow nesting them, combined with third party libraries that contain types that wrap nested dynamic arrays like that and intentionally don't provide ways to change the size of the internal dynamic arrays. It would, be possible to include a type like that in a language's standard library, or even at the type system level. Again, whether that should be done is a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I have never dealt with theoretical issues, but through dealing with programming I will say the following: We have the types null, bool, num, string. Everything else will arise from them. eg any = (null || bool || num || string). On the other hand, arrays are not types but forms of organization of types. So if I look at this ['aaa','bbv'] from the outside I'll say it's an array, but to tell what type it is I have to see the inside. If all the internal elements are of the same type then we can say that we have an array of type e.g. String, otherwise we have an array of type any. So, since the array is not a type but a form of organization, it is also necessary for the any type